# show bokeh plot with chromium-embedded-framework?

Tags: bokeh, chromium-embedded, cefpython

I have built a bokeh plot which offers interactive plots with bokeh server. What should I do if I want to show this Bokeh Plot with Chromium embedded framework, rather than some web browsers like Chrome or FireFox?

Answer (score 1):

You can find cefpython hello world program here:
https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/hello_world.py

Just change url from google.com to your local web server.

Comment: I am really new to the local web server, can you tell me what's the path of my local server if using bokeh server? @Czarek Tomczak